# Vmware Esxi PSOD - Veeam backup

Tags: veeam

I have an HP ProLiant 380 Gen8 with Vmware Esxi 5.5 Build 1331820 Installed on it
The data store on this server is 2TB (free 200GB) one of the virtual machines with 1.5TB disk space

This issue started when I created a Virtual Machine for Windows 2016 and installed Veeam Backup and replication 10

When I created the first backup job I got the first PSOD (Purple Screen of death)
I suspected because of the Snapshot Veeam created for the virtual machine 1.5TB, the DataStore space was very low.

I created a new datastore from LUN / QNAP NAS Storage (this is the backup destination - but the LUN space is separated from the backup destination),  I changed the snapshots working directory into the new LUN DataStore.

I repeated the backup process and i got another PSOD knowing i have enough space.

Please check the below images from the PSOF i am getting

[PSOD1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOvQn.png)
[PSOD2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbYph.png)
[PSOD3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNEaT.png)

i tried to export the dump logs but i cannot know what is the issue there.

Please Help and thank you in advance.

Comment: ESXi 5.5 [has been End of Life since 2018 (!)](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/51491). Update to a supported version.

Comment: Veeam 10 doesn't support ESXi 5.x any more. You need to use an older version or upgrade the host. Additionally, you must *not ever* run out of storage space. Add disks early on and monitor free space. Mind that the original storage location still needs some space for snapshots, even when they're redirected.